# Primal attack On Kyber algorithm specifications

Tags: attack, lwe, kyber

In the Kyber Algorithm specifications document, chapter 5.1.2 primal attack, it says that:

> Given the matrix LWE instance $(A,b=As+e)$, one builds the lattice $\Lambda = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}^{m+kn+1}:(A\vert I_m\vert -b)x=0 \,mod \,q\}$ of dimension $d=m+kn+1$, volume $q^m$, and with a unique-SVP solution $v=(s,e,1)$ of norm $\lambda\approx\varsigma\sqrt{kn+m}$, where $\varsigma$ is the standard deviation of the individual secret/error coefficients.

To my mind, $\Lambda = q\,L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)^{\lor}$, where $L^{\lor}$ represent the dual of lattice $L$.and $L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)^{\lor}=L(b_1, \dots, b_{m})$, where $b_i$ is the column vector with $b_i^{(j)}$ represtion its j-th component(start from 0), satisfy
$$b_i^{(nk+i-1)}=1, b_i^{(nk+j)}=0, j\ne i-1, i=1, \dots, m.$$
So $\Lambda =L(q\,b_1,\dots,q\,b_{m})$...

Is that correct?

If it is right, then how can $v=(s,e,1)$ be linearly represented by $q\,b_1,\dots,q\,b_{m}$?

If this is not right, how can I figure out

> What is the basis of $\Lambda$ ?

and

> Why is the volume $q^m$?

Or, are there any references?

Comment: Since $L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)\subset L(I_{kn + m + 1})$, by corollary 2.7 (2) in [the different ideal](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf)，
that is $L_1 \subset L_2 \Longleftrightarrow L_2^\lor \subset L_1^\lor$, so I can sure $L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)^\lor \supset L(I_{kn + m + 1})^\lor = L(I_{kn + m + 1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whereas it is true that each of the $b_i$ vectors lies in the dual to the lattice generated by the rows of $A|I_m|b$, there are vectors in the dual that do not lie in the span of the $b_i$. For instance, let $\mathbf w\in \mathbb Z^{kn}$ be any vector in the row span of $A^{-1}$ then $(\mathbf w|0|0)$ is also in the dual. Likewise the vector $\frac1q(s,e,1)$ lies in the dual, but not in the span of the $b_i$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You are right. But how can I figure out the basis of $\Lambda$ and why is the volume $q^m$.
Since $ L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)\subset L(I_{kn + m + 1})$, by corollary 2.7 (2) in [the different ideal](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/different.pdf)，
that is $L_1 \subset L_2 \Longleftrightarrow L_2^\lor \subset L_1^\lor$, so I can sure $L(A\vert I_m\vert -b)^\lor \supset L(I_{kn + m + 1})^\lor = L(I_{kn + m + 1})$.